# Is there a limit on how many custom objects that can be inserted at the same time?

Tags: apex, custom-object, limits

When I insert over 200 records it stops at 200. Here is the code:

```
   try {
       Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(customObjs);
       // prints 203 which is what I expect
       system.debug(srList.size());
   } catch(Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
   }
   // prints 200 even though it should be 203
   system.debug([SELECT count() FROM Custom_Object__c]);
```

Is there a limit on how many custom objects that can be inserted at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert(Or any other DML operation) only 10k records (custom or standard) at a time. It is a salesforce governor limit. If you have more than that, you might have to go for apex batch.

Comment: it's stopping at 200 for some reason. SaveResult says 203 which is how many I inserted but when I query to see how many were inserted it says 200

Comment: srList is a list of SaveResult. It will show all the records passed and failed. In individual save result record there will be a flag isSuccess to decide if it is successfully inserted. But again all these come into picture only if you are using Database.insert(customObjs,false). Is it going to catch block?

Comment: It's not going to the catch block and I just added a loop through the srList and it's not showing any errors either

Comment: That is odd. Is there anything else causing deletion of records? Like trigger or something?. If not you might have to raise a ticket with salesforce

Comment: I think I just found out what's happening. There is a trigger that is being called and deleting what gets inserted but only works in batches of 200 so it deletes all of them instead of just the 200 that it processed in that batch. Thanks for the brainstorming!